# Black dots and lines in the 3d view

Tags: 3d-view

[image: 3d view problem!]

I have a 3d view problem in Blender 3.2.1.

Black dots and lines in the 3d view of the program.

Comment: Please try to ask your question in English here so we can help you. Thank you!

Comment: Check that your graphics card drivers are up to date.

Comment: Hello and welcome. English is mandatory language for the site. If you are not comfortable writing in English feel free to use any online translation service.